# IEnumerable filter

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

How do I add a filter so that I only return RelationshipTypeIDs 26-30?

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListOptions> GetRelationshipTypes()
{
    return (from q in unitOfWork.GenericRepository<tlkpRelationshipType>().Get()
            select new SelectListOptions
            {
                Value = q.RelationshipTypeID.ToString(),
                Label = q.RelationshipType
            }
            ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please don't give negative marks to the above question. It could block him permanently to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `where` clause like so:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListOptions> GetRelationshipTypes()
{
    return (from q in unitOfWork.GenericRepository<tlkpRelationshipType>().Get()
            where q.RelationshipTypeID >= 26 && q.RelationshipTypeID <= 30
            select new SelectListOptions
            {
                Value = q.RelationshipTypeID.ToString(),
                Label = q.RelationshipType
            }
            ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (from q in unitOfWork.GenericRepository<tlkpRelationshipType>().Get()
        where q.RelationshipTypeID >= 26
        where q.RelationshipTypeID <= 30
        select new SelectListOptions
```